# BarCode/QRcode Processing with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, barcode, qr-code

is it possible to read and process QR-Codes/Bar-codes without using a scanner with iPhone?

if so please mention what api is used and what frameworks are required?

**Thanks**.

Comment: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

on the github page they have a good explanation on what prerequisites the library has

Comment: this library does not require any scanner? and i can do the job with iPhone/iPad' camera?

Comment: what do you mean by scanner? the camera IS the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to [ZBAR](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/index.html). It has very good API documentation and easy to implement

Comment: will using it require a scanner or iPhone/iPad camera will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Check these libray

[ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/index.html) an open source software for reading bar codes.
[ZXing](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) a library written in Java and then ported to Objective C / C++ (QR code only). [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC)

Comment: ZXing is not qr-code only. Don't know about the ZXingObjC port.